# Why isn't my javascript created text centering?

Tags: javascript, css, timer

For some reason the text output by my race countdown timer is only center aligning to the left side of the text. I cannot figure out why it's doing this despite setting the CSS to center the text.

EDIT: I believe I've narrowed this down to a font rendering issue, if I turn off Franchise it centers fine but with Franchise on it aligns all weirdly (Seems to be due to the "space" the font takes up being very small physically but visually it's not the same). If anyone has any ideas on how I can resolve this that'd be awesome.

NOTE: This is only happening in Chrome and Safari. It centers fine in Firefox.

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="card card-race">
 <div class="h">
 <h5 class="subheading letter-space">NEXT RACE IN...</h5>
 </div>
 <div class="bd">
 <span id="countdown"></span>
 </div>
 <div class="cta cta-2">
  <a href="#watch" class="btn btn-blue boxer"><i class="icon-play"></i>Watch</a>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-blue"><i class="icon-flag"></i>Recap</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS(SCSS):

```
.card.card-race {
        background:darken($blue,30%);
        .bd {
            border: none;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .h {
            border:none;
            background:$blue;
        }
    }
    #countdown {
        font-family:'franchise';
        font-size: 3.8em;
        line-height: 1em;
        display:block;
        padding:18px 0;
        @include media(tablet) {
            padding-top:5px;
            font-size: 2.7em;
        }
    }
```

Javascript:

```
// Race Dates
        var raceDates = ["May 18, 2014", "June 7, 2014", "June 22, 2014"];
        var start = "May 18, 2014";
        // set the date we're counting down to
        var target_date = new Date(raceDates[0]).getTime();

        // variables for time units
        var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

        // get tag element
        var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

        // update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
        setInterval(function () {

        // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
        var current_date = new Date().getTime();
        var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

        // do some time calculations
        days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
        seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

        hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
        seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

        minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
        seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

        // format countdown string + set tag value
        countdown.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h"
        ;


      }, 1000);
```

Comment: It [centres fine here](http://jsbin.com/zirazitu/1/edit), whatever your problem is, it isn't in the code you've shared.

Comment: It's also fine here in a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6emAL/)**. Could be some external CSS that's not shared.

Comment: No it's not centering fine in Chrome or Safari, though it does work in Firefox.

Comment: I've just tested it in Chrome, it is centred.

Comment: I'm seeing this: http://bit.ly/1nF006k Which doesn't look centered to me.

Answer (score -1):

Try making your bd div width="100%"